# Check Package Name is present in database or not

Tags: android

my main class to show all the apps is below where i have made a onclick listener to select a app and then send to check it  if it is present in database

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity implements OnItemClickListener {

    private ArrayList<String> application_name = new ArrayList<String>();

    List<ResolveInfo> list;

    String[] myapps_name= new String[application_name.size()];
    ResolveInfo rInfo;
    String error;
    String packagename;
    String returnedPackageName;
    public boolean myappisindatabase=false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        PackageManager pm = this.getPackageManager();

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);

        list = pm.queryIntentActivities(intent, PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
        for (ResolveInfo rInfo: list) {
            application_name.add((String) rInfo.activityInfo.applicationInfo.loadLabel(pm));
            Log.w("Installed Applications", rInfo.activityInfo.applicationInfo.loadLabel(pm).toString());
        }

        getListView().setOnItemClickListener(this);
        myapps_name = application_name.toArray(myapps_name);
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, myapps_name));
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
        final ActivityInfo info = list.get(arg2).activityInfo;
        packagename = info.packageName;

        checkifindatabase();

        if(!myappisindatabase) {
            AlertDialog.Builder a = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            a.setMessage("Do you want to lock this app");
            a.setCancelable(true);
            a.setPositiveButton("Yes, lock my app", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    boolean diditwork = true;
                    try {
                        Mylockedapps entry = new Mylockedapps(MainActivity.this);
                        entry.open();
                        entry.createEntry(packagename);
                        entry.close();
                    } catch(Exception e) {
                        diditwork = false;
                        error = e.toString();
                        Intent didntwork= new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                        startActivity(didntwork);
                    } finally {
                        if (diditwork) {
                            Intent databaseadd= new Intent(MainActivity.this, DatabaseView.class);
                            startActivity(databaseadd);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });

            AlertDialog alert= a.create();
            a.show();
        }

        if (myappisindatabase) {
            AlertDialog.Builder a= new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            a.setMessage("Do you want to unlock this app");
            a.setCancelable(true);
            a.setPositiveButton("Yes, unlock my app", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    boolean diditdelete= true;
                    try {
                        Mylockedapps entry= new Mylockedapps(MainActivity.this);
                        entry.open();
                        entry.deleteEntry(packagename);
                        entry.close();
                    } catch(Exception e) {
                        diditdelete = false;
                        error = e.toString();
                        Intent didntwork = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                        startActivity(didntwork);
                    } finally {
                        if (diditdelete) {
                            Intent deleted = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Deleted.class);
                            startActivity(deleted);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });

            AlertDialog alert = a.create();
            a.show();
        }
    }

    public boolean checkifindatabase() {
        boolean diditfind = true;
        try {
            Mylockedapps myapp = new Mylockedapps(this);
            myapp.open();
            returnedPackageName = myapp.getPackageName(packagename);
            myapp.close();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            diditfind = false;
            error = e.toString();
            Intent didntwork = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Found.class);
            startActivity(didntwork);
        }

        if(packagename.equals(returnedPackageName))
            myappisindatabase=true;
        else
            myappisindatabase=false;

        return true;
    }
}
```

and my database class is

```
public class Mylockedapps {
    public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
    public static final String APPS_PACKAGENAME = "apps_packagename";

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "MyLockedApps";
    private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "AppsTable";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    private DbHelper ourHelper;
    private final Context ourContext;
    private SQLiteDatabase ourDatabase;

    private static class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        public DbHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null,DATABASE_VERSION);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + "(" +
                        KEY_ROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                        APPS_PACKAGENAME + " TEXT NOT NULL);");
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion,
                              int newVersion) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXITS " + DATABASE_TABLE);
            onCreate(db);
        }
    }

    public Mylockedapps(Context c) {
        ourContext = c;
    }

    public Mylockedapps open() throws SQLException {
        ourHelper = new DbHelper(ourContext);
        ourDatabase = ourHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    public void close() {
        ourHelper.close();
    }

    public long createEntry(String packagename) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(APPS_PACKAGENAME, packagename);
        return ourDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);
    }

    public String getData() {
        String[] columns = new String[]{KEY_ROWID,APPS_PACKAGENAME};
        Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null, null, null, null, null);
        String result = "";
        int iRow = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ROWID);
        int iApps = c.getColumnIndex(APPS_PACKAGENAME);

        for(c.moveToFirst();!c.isAfterLast();c.moveToNext()) {
            result= result + c.getString(iRow) + " " + c.getString(iApps) + "\n";
        }
        return result;
    } 

    public String getPackageName(String findthisapp) throws SQLException {
        String[] columns = new String[]{KEY_ROWID,APPS_PACKAGENAME};
        Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, APPS_PACKAGENAME , null, null, null, null, null);

        if (c != null) {
            c.moveToFirst();
            String packagename = c.getString(1);

            if (packagename.equals(findthisapp))
                return packagename;
            else 
                return null;
        }
        return null;
    }

    public void deleteEntry (String packagename)throws SQLException {
        ourDatabase.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, APPS_PACKAGENAME + "=" + packagename, null);
    }
}
```

and my error is

```
close() was never explicitly called on database '/data/data/com.ku.installedapps/databases/MyLockedApps' 
android.database.sqlite.DatabaseObjectNotClosedException: Application did not close the      cursor or database object that was opened here
```

and similarly other errors.....
I think m getting error while i send a string to check if it matches with anyone of the package name stored in database at part

```
public String getPackageName(String findthisapp) throws SQLException{
```

Comment: It seems that inside `checkifindatabase()` if there was exception then the close() function is never called. So that's why it might be showing exception. Try to use debugger to see where it fails. It might help.

Comment: please help..project submission last day...

Comment: Post your full error stack trace from LogCat.

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't have full LogCat here, what I am guessing from the given error is that you somewhere you call `myapp.open();` but you don't call `myapp.close();`. What I am guessing is that if your function `myapp.getPackageName(packagename);` returns error then you `myapp.close()` never gets called and thus results in the error that you see.
Just try and call open(), close() outside try-catch block.

Put this in OnCreate() function:

```
Mylockedapps myapp = new Mylockedapps(this);
try{
    myapp.open();

}catch(SQLException e){

}
```

Leave your checkifindatabase() function like this:

```
public boolean checkifindatabase() {
    boolean diditfind = true;

    try {
        returnedPackageName = myapp.getPackageName(packagename);
    } catch(Exception e) {
        diditfind = false;
        error = e.toString();
        Intent didntwork = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Found.class);
        startActivity(didntwork);
    }
    if(packagename.equals(returnedPackageName))
        myappisindatabase=true;
    else
        myappisindatabase=false;

    return true;
}
```

Inside your onPause() function call:

```
myapp.close();
```

This will insure that you always close it. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You have to **close the cursor** this way

```
public String getPackageName(String findthisapp) throws SQLException{
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String[] columns= new String[]{KEY_ROWID,APPS_PACKAGENAME};
        Cursor c= ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, APPS_PACKAGENAME , null, null, null, null, null);
        if(c.getCount()!=0){
            c.moveToFirst();
            String packagename= c.getString(1);
            if(packagename.equals(findthisapp)){
                c.close();
                return packagename;
            }else{
                c.close();
                return null;
            }
        }
        c.close();
        return null;
    }
```